# .Net 3.5 - Best way to communicate with another .Net Process?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a library that interacts with our phone system, ie, Hey phone, call this number for me.  This library is used in one of our in house products.  I would like to put this instead in a service, so that any of our in house products can send the service a message to place a phone call.  So basically I want to communicate from a program built in .Net 3.5 with a service running on the same machine also built in the 3.5 framework.  I have done some work with WCF and was considering using this but thought I would ask what others have done or would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think WCF is perfectly suited to this.. It allows you to separate your plumbing from your application code, and the configuration allows you to easily change transports(http, tcp, named pipes), add  security, throttling, etc., without writing more code.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. WCF is a good one. Depending on the circumstance, you might want to consider named pipes, [IpcChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel.aspx), sockets and other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Doh, dont know why i Didnt find this link before, more or less what I want to do.  My previous work was using a TCP connection, this one uses named pipes:
[Expose a WCF Service through a Named Pipes binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184878/expose-a-wcf-service-through-a-named-pipes-binding)

Answer (score 0):

I find WCF overcomplicated. I would use MSMQ either directly or via [Spring.Framework Messaging](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/msmq.html)

Comment: Ironically, I actually find your suggest the more complicated one.  I find WCF actually completely simple and easy to start with.  That said, I will describe it as problematic and will honestly admit you will spend way more time solving WCF problems than you ever did implementing solutions.   Overall though, I do recommend the technology.