# WCF based WinForms app in standalone mode

Tags: winforms, wcf, architecture, soa, n-tier-architecture

I have a windows application that has its business logic layer implemented as a WCF service. This service is currently hosted on IIS. I wanted to know that if there's a way where I could optionally run the application in standalone mode when a service isn't available/feasible.

Answer (score 1):

In proper design, the business logic really shouldn't be implemented as a WCF service directly - it should abstracted out into a separate assembly for reasons just like yours, and the WCF wrapper should instead simply reference it. I'm guessing you didn't have a say in this [non-orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science) design.

If you have access to the WCF assemblies, you could distribute them with your standalone application and reference them, and then call into those WCF operations without activating it as a service. It would be rather ugly but it would work, assuming none of the business logic depends on any WCF-activated features.

**edit re comments:** You can have multiple service hosts and endpoints and keep the same contract ("interface") in WCF. Perhaps you want to add some [self hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) that exposes a [named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184878/expose-a-wcf-service-through-a-named-pipes-binding) endpoint, and access the operations that way in your application.

Comment: @Mike. Thank you for the answer. The reason I don't want to refer the business logic assemblies directly is because I want to keep the interface of communication between the application and the service common for both scenarios.

Comment: @Mike I think I wasn't able to communicate my problem accurately. Maybe the solution I went for will make it clear. I embedded an http server into my application to host the service in case if a remote server isn't specified. I wanted to make no direct references to the service assembly or the objects being passed around.

Comment: Yes, so you did self-host :) Cool.